# Node CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: node.js, cors, localhost

I am using two server of port 8080 and 8082, where 8082 works on client side and 8080 acts as a middleware.
I am making a http callout from server to middleware using a html button, but it gives an error "**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/' from origin 'http://localhost:8082' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**"

Attaching the code:
**Server.js**

```
var http = require('http');  
var url = require('url');  
var fs = require('fs');  
var cors = require('cors');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response,next) {  
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;  
    switch (path) {  
        case '/':  
            response.writeHead(200, {  
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain'  
            });  
            response.write("This is Test Message.");  
            response.end();  
            break;  
        case '/server.html':  
            fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data) {  
                if (error) {  
                    response.writeHead(404);  
                    response.write(error);  
                    response.end();  
                } else {

                    response.writeHead(200, {  
                        'Content-Type': 'text/html'  
                    });  
                    response.write(data);  
                    response.end();  
                }  
            });  
            break;  
        case '/HtmlPage2.html':  
            fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data) {  
                if (error) {  
                    response.writeHead(404);  
                    response.write(error);  
                    response.end();  
                } else {  
                    response.writeHead(200, {  
                        'Content-Type': 'text/html'  
                    });  
                    response.write(data);  
                    response.end();  
                }  
            });  
            break;  
        default:  
            response.writeHead(404);  
            response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");  
            response.end();  
            break;  
    }  
});  
server.listen(8082);
```

---

**Server.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="server.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          function callServer(){
            $.get('http://localhost:8080', function(returnResult) {

            });
            }  
            </script>
    </head>
<body>
        <button onclick="callServer()">Click</button>
</body>
```

**MiddleWareServer.js**

```
var http = require('http');  
var url = require('url');  
var fs = require('fs');  
var cors = require('cors');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response,next) {   
    response.writeHead(200, {  
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'  
    });  
    function returnResult(){
        console.log('Called from the port:8082');
    }
    response.write("Port 8080 started..");  
    response.end();  
});  
server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Both of your "servers" include express and enable cors... but nether actually use express, so that configuration does nothing.

Comment: I was compelled to use express but i want to do it with native node code. @KevinB So, what the solution for this?

Comment: Either attach express to your server, or have your request handler handle all of the CORS requirements directly (by determining what kind of request is coming in and responding accordingly with correct headers/status/content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just used Express and it worked .. Replacing and posting new files:
These file will fulfill the following features :

1. Create and start two different server.
2. Call the middleware server from a html file from 8082 port.
3. Fetch the response in html file from middle ware server.

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
router.get('/server',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/server.html'));
});
app.use('/', router);
app.listen(8082);
console.log('Running at Port 8082');
```

**MiddleWareServer.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Localhost:8080 has been Started'));
app.post('/middlewarehit', function(req,res){
    res.end('Localhost:8080 Hit');
    } 
);
app.listen(8080);
console.log('Running at Port 8080');
```

**server.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          function callServer(){
            $.ajax({
              url: "http://localhost:8080/middlewarehit",
              type: "POST",
              dataType: '',
              success: function(res){
                $('#response').val(res);
              }
          });
        }  
            </script>
    </head>
<body>
        <input type="text" id="response">
        <button onclick="callServer()">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you use express.

**MiddleWareServer.js**

```
var cors = require('cors');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', function(request, response, next) {   
    response.send("Port 8080 started.."); 
})

express.listen(8080);
```

Sending a get request to `localhost:8080` would return `Port 8080 started..`.

Same goes for **Server.js**.

Comment: I was compelled to use express @Dijkstra , what if i dont want to use express?